# reduce header row space in renderDataTable

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I have a few `renderDataTable` in a shiny app that I have developed [here](http://www.wittgensteincentre.org/dataexplorer)... where I will only ever have one row (see for example all tables in the Glossary tab) in the table

[image]

It made sense to drop the filter, search and other features that display by default at the top of the table using the following options in renderDataTable;

```
list(bFilter = FALSE, bAutoWidth =FALSE, bInfo=FALSE, bPaginate=FALSE)
```

however this leaves me with a sizeable white space above the table, I guess from the empty row above the header or the header row itself. Either way I can not figure out how to eliminate the white space?

Comment: @jdharrison. thanks for the link. "sDom" = "rt" worked.